# Twitter Bootstrap Toggle Button (bootstrap-button.js) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I have a simple button like they have in the demo:

```
<button id="track" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Track</button>
```

and in my application.js file I added:

```
$('#track').button();

$('#track').live('click', function(event) {
    alert('hello!');
});
```

I added the alert call as a double check - it works.  I can confirm that the `bootstrap-button.js` script is loading and only once.  I have played with the javascript load order and that does not seem to make a difference:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require active_admin
```

I did manage to get it to work once by manually inserting a script tag with `bootstrap-button.js` inline after the button but now I can't even re-create that!.

I have Googled and read pretty much all the SO posts on these issues but I figure I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Why are you including the bootstrap script twice? That has been known to cause problems. Remove one of them and it should work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question in here!  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am going to try deleteing the bootstrap reference when I get home.  As for the question and what I am trying to accomplish: the question is am I missing some obvious here that would cause this to fail.  What I am ultimatly trying to have is a toggle button to 'track' an item.  Once I get the toggle to work I was going to add the logic to make a AJAX call to the controler to set / unset the 'track' (like adding a favorite etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to @andres-ilich for getting me thinking.  active_admin was the conflict.  If I load it before twitter/boorstrap it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at bootstrap switch plugin

Simply use this in the body of your html

```
<div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

See [this link](http://www.larentis.eu/switch/) for further details on the plugins and more advanced examples

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. I'm going to accept this, trusting that you'll amend your answer.